# kafka as message dispatcher to flink - partitioning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a process that needs to dispatch certain data to flink cluster (via kafka) consisting of 3 nodes. There will be two different topics in total as far as I can predict. All messages will be timestamped. Order of messages must persist.

I am not able to understand the mechanism behind message partitioning (key). If I wish to have a simple message dispatcher as described above, is a message partition important? If so, based on what should I pick it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what ordering you need (by some UUID, server producing the data,  some other event type, etc), but Kafka message ordering is only guaranteed within partitions of any topic, and any Kafka consumers including Flink are guaranteed to read its assigned partition in order.

[The default Kafka partitioner by the producer will use a Murmur2 hash algorithm](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L54-L71) if you've specified a key. If you have a null key, then it will round-robin all the partitions evenly.

Flink producer overwrites this behavior last time I checked. See [**FLINK-9610**](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6181). If you are using Flink as a consumer only, then you don't need to worry about this.

Messages are timestamped in Kafka by default

Comment: Same order as the process dispatched (published) the message.

Comment: Okay, and are you not seeing consumers getting the same order?

Comment: No, I am just not understanding the kafka partitioning. I see sometimes key:value being the same, I think I'm not alone struggling to understand it's concept :)

Comment: Using what producer client? In Java, look at https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L54-L71

Comment: OK, then based on what is my message key suppose to be? Basically same question as stated above :)

Comment: There is no answer for what your key "should be". It's up to you... All that really matters for this answer is that the same key will hit the same partition, and will be in order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179766/discussion-between-krizajb-and-cricket-007).